# I can't get contentOwnerID on youtube API

Tags: youtube-api

I can't get contentOwnerID on youtube API.

```
$contentOwnersListResponse = $youtubePartner->contentOwners->listContentOwners(array('fetchMine' => true));
$contentOwnerId = $contentOwnersListResponse['items'][0]['id'];
```

this code can't get contentOwnerID. I'm using sample code from here [Uploading and Monetizing a Video

][1](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/code_samples/php#uploading_and_monetizing_a_video).

Why I can't get contentOwnerID? Please help me.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I get this error. Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/contentOwners?fetchMine=true: (403) Insufficient Permission